# Pytorch-lightning strange error: implemented method that does not override its parent's method

Tags: python, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to use the library Pytorch Lightning, but I am encountering a strange error that I am not able to solve. I cannot provide a minimal working implementation since my code is split across several modules and does not use many pre-built components. Furthermore, I cannot share the data I am using. However, I hope to find some help.

Basically, I use a VGG network that implements the methods required by the pytorch-lightning library:

```
import pytorch_lightning as pl
[...]

class VGG(pl.LightningModule):
   [...]

   def forward(self, x):
       x = self.conv_layers(x)
       x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
       x = self.output(x)
       return x

   def configure_optimizers(self):
    # in the docs on the pytorch-lightning website, the self.parameters() 
    # below appears both with parentheses and without, 
    # i.e., both self.parameters() and self.paramters
    # I tried both with no changes
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(self.parameters(), lr=self.config["learning_rate"], momentum=self.config["momentum"])
    lr_scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, 'min', factor=0.05, patience=5, cooldown=0, verbose=True)
    return optimizer, lr_scheduler

   def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
       x, y = batch
       y_hat = self.forward(x)
       loss =  F.cross_entropy(y_hat, y)
       return {'loss':loss}
```

I have a `DataModule` providing the training, validation and test data:

```
from pytorch_lightning import LightningDataModule

class MyDataModule(LightningDataModule):
def train_dataloader(self):
        if self.train_DL is None:
            self.train_DL = self._from_indexes_to_dataloader("train_i.tsv")
        return self.train_DL
    
    def val_dataloader(self):
        if self.valid_DL is None:
            self.valid_DL = self._from_indexes_to_dataloader("valid_i.tsv")
        return self.valid_DL
    
    def test_dataloader(self):
        if self.test_DL is None:
            self.test_DL = self._from_indexes_to_dataloader("test_i.tsv")
        return self.test_DL
```

An external script tries to train the model with:

```
import pytorch_lightning as pl
[...]
model = VGG(config)
trainer = pl.Trainer(gpus=1, max_epochs=config["n_epochs"], progress_bar_refresh_rate=5)
datamodule = MyDataModule(config, logger=log)
trainer.fit(model, datamodule)
```

But when I try and run it, `pytorch-lightning` tells me I forgot to implement the method `training_step`:

```
pytorch_lightning.utilities.exceptions.MisconfigurationException: 
No `training_step()` method defined. 
Lightning `Trainer` expects as minimum a `training_step()`, `train_dataloader()` and `configure_optimizers()` to be defined.
```

The error is caused by the fact that their checker `pytorch_lightning.utilities.model_helpers.py` does not consider my `VGG` to have overridden the `training_step` method. In its `is_overriden(.)` method:

```
def is_overridden(method_name: str, model: Union[LightningModule, LightningDataModule]) -> bool:
    # if you pass DataModule instead of None or a LightningModule, we use LightningDataModule as super
    # TODO - refector this function to accept model_name, instance, parent so it makes more sense
    super_object = LightningModule if not isinstance(model, LightningDataModule) else LightningDataModule

    if not hasattr(model, method_name) or not hasattr(super_object, method_name):
        # in case of calling deprecated method
        return False
    instance_attr = getattr(model, method_name)
       
    if not instance_attr:
        return False
    super_attr = getattr(super_object, method_name)

    # when code pointers are different, it was implemented
    if hasattr(instance_attr, 'patch_loader_code'):
        # cannot pickle __code__ so cannot verify if PatchDataloader
        # exists which shows dataloader methods have been overwritten.
        # so, we hack it by using the string representation
        is_overridden = instance_attr.patch_loader_code != str(super_attr.__code__)
    else:
        is_overridden = instance_attr.__code__ is not super_attr.__code__
        print(method_name)
        print(instance_attr.__code__)
        print(super_attr.__code__)
        print(f'last is_overriden should be True, but it is {is_overridden}')
    return is_overridden
```

the last check fails. The output of the `print` I added is:

```
training_step
<code object training_step at 0x7f22e26cc870, file "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/lightning.py", line 531>
<code object training_step at 0x7f22e26cc870, file "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/lightning.py", line 531>
last is_overriden should be True, but it is False
```

Basically the `training_step` in my `VGG` class "poins to" the same code of its superclass. Is there anyone who can tell me why it does not consider `VGG` to override the method of its parent?

Is there anyone who can tell me what I should look at?
I tried to ask on their support forum, but my question, as many others, remained unanswered.

The `VGG`, the datasets and the `pytorch DataLoader` work correctly when used without `pytorch-lightning` with `pytorch` only.